# JAVA How to write an int into a file?

Tags: java, file, int, writer

I am supposed to create a file (done, it's called "factoriales.txt") and print in it the value of 10! (which is 3628800), the thing is, I can't seem to write the value into a file. I already know how to write text, but this wont work.... here's what I have so far. Please help!

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class D09T9e2
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                File fac = new File("factoriales.txt");
                if (!fac.exists())
                {
                    fac.createNewFile();
                }
                System.out.println("The file has been created.");
                int r = 1;
                for (int i = 1; i<=10; i--)
                {
                    r = r * i;
                }
                FileWriter write = new FileWriter(fac);
                write.write(""+r);
                write.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Here's how I solved it thanks to everybody in here, I hope you like this simple method:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class D09T9e2
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                File fac = new File("factoriales.txt");
                if (!fac.exists())
                {
                    fac.createNewFile();
                }
                System.out.println("\n----------------------------------");
                System.out.println("The file has been created.");
                System.out.println("------------------------------------");
                int r = 1;
                FileWriter wr = new FileWriter(fac);
                for (int i = 1; i<=10; i++)
                {
                    r = r * i;
                    wr.write(r+System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
                }               
                wr.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: int cant hold 10!, use a long

Answer (score 2):

the reason any way is that

```
for (int i = 1; i<=10; i--)
```

runs to infinity since 1 cannot be reduced to 10

it should be

```
for (int i = 1; i<=10; i++)
```

and change data type to long as well

Comment: Technically, 1 will reduce to 10. It would take (2^32 - 9) iterations though

Comment: :D didnt count on that

Comment: In this exact case i = 1, 0, -1, -2,..., -2147483648, +2147483647. Therefore, the loop will run 2147483650 times

Comment: Lol I'm such an idiot... I did it and now it did write something but it was just an "?"... Why is that?

Comment: only thing i could guess is that the char value of the int was taken
you used int or long?

Comment: well I added this to convert it (I'm new at java so I don't know much sorry xD)

Comment: well I added this, trying to convert it (but I'm new at java sorry lol)

        Long l = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(r));
        int back = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(l));

Comment: just forget int and modify above posted code for long [primitive not wrapper] and use `write()` to write on file

Comment: xD Thanks for the help, as I said, I don't know much about java, so I just converted the Int to String instead and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Change the for-loop:

From

```
 for (int i = 1; i<=10; i--)
```

to

```
 for (int i = 1; i<=10; i++)
```

and you will get the right result.

have a try and go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       try
       {
           File fac = new File("c:\\bea\\factoriales.txt");
           if (!fac.exists())
           {
               fac.createNewFile();
           }
           System.out.println("The file has been created.");
           int r = 1;
           FileWriter write = new FileWriter(fac);
           write.write("");
           for (int i = 1; i<=10; i++)
           {
               r = r * i;
               write.append(r + "\n");
           }

           write.flush();
            write.close();
       }
       catch (IOException e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```

Output:

```
1
2
6
24
120
720
5040
40320
362880
3628800
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I checked and that's exactly what I had to do xD but can you tell me how can I get the \n to work in a text file? It displays the answer in the same line.

Comment: Oh, nevermind I fixed it with a System.getProperty( "line.separator" ) right after the (""+r...
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save a number in text format use PrintWriter, it has methods for writing numbers.